# Calling a static method from a generic constraint Dart

Tags: generics, dart

I'm trying to call a static method from a generic type I receive.
Is that even possible?

Furthermore, I apply a Type constraint in order to only manipulate the object from its parent class.

Here is a short example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```dart
class A {
  static func() {
    print("A");
  }
}

class B extends A {
  static func() {
    print("B");
  }
}

concret<T extends A>() {
  T.func(); // I expected a print('B')
}

main() {
    concret<B>();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Dart static method invocations are resolved at compile-time, so it's not possible to call them on type variables which only have a value at run-time.

If it was possible, it would be completely unsafe. Anyone can create a class `C` extending `A` which does not have a static `func` member and invoke `concret<C>();`. Since static members are not inherited, it would have to give you a run-time error, and there is nothing you can do to detect that at compile-time. That is the primary reason why it is not allowed.

Comment: So the dart standard of having a factory `factory SomeClass.fromOtherClass(OtherClass otherClass)` would only be callable in its abstract form if we change it to `OtherClass().toSomeClass()`. This troubles me more than it should.