# How do i invoke method on a generic type in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

There are several models have a same structure, { type: xxx, settings: xxx}, so i would like to use a parent class "WidgetConfig" with a generic type "T" to implement this, but problem occurs when i add "fromJson" methods. How can i invoke method on a generic type or any other ways to implement this?

```
class BannerWidgetViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  WidgetConfig<BannerWidgetConfig> config;

  BannerWidgetViewModel(String configJson){
    config = WidgetConfig.fromJson(configJson);
  }
}

class BannerWidgetConfig {
  String imgUrl;
  String padImgUrl;
  String lessonId;

  BannerWidgetConfig.fromJson(json){
    if (json != null) {
      this.imgUrl = json['imgUrl'];
      this.padImgUrl = json['padImgUrl'];
      this.lessonId = json['lessonId'];
    }
  }
}

class WidgetConfig<T> {
  WidgetType type;

  WidgetConfig.fromJson(json){
    if (json != null) {
      this.type = json['type'];
      // this.settings = T.fromJson(json['settings']); // T doesn't have fromJson method
    }
  }
}
```

---

then i use a abstract class but still not working.

```
abstract class BaseWidgetConfig {
  BaseWidgetConfig.fromJson(dynamic json);
}

class WidgetConfig<T extends BaseWidgetConfig> {
  WidgetType type;
  T settings;

  WidgetConfig.fromJson(json){
    if (json != null) {
      this.type = json['type'];
      this.settings = T.fromJson();
    }
  }
}
```

[code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iDuW.jpg)

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was unfortunately incorrect. [You cannot invoke a static method/constructor on a generic type.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56138419/3158312). You may try to use [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) though.

Comment: thanks a lot, according the answer in that reference, it is indeed not possible i think

Answer (score 0):

Directly show the function as a reference.

**send function as a reference here.**

```
FireStoreHelper.getList<ModelLesson>('grade4', ModelLesson.fromJson);
```

**get the method here.**

```
static Future<List<T>> getList<T>(String path, Function fromJson)
```