# Calling static method on type parameter renders method not defined error

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Suppose this method:

```
  T? reviveObject<T>( dynamic value ) {

    if (  ( value is Map )
       && value.containsKey( '_type_' )
       && ( T.toString() == value[ '_type_' ] )
    ) {
      print( '!! ' + T.toString()  );
      return T.fromJson( value as Map<String, dynamic> );
    }

    return null;

  }
```

`reviveObject` decodes some `JSON` to revive an object of `T`.

When called using e.g. `reviveObject<EItem>(value )`, `EItem` actually does have a `EItem.fromJson()` method.

Unfortunately, the type checker complains, that `fromJson()` **is not defined** in the above generic method.

**How do I make the type checker not complain?**

Comment: Try using `T == Map`

Comment: How is the compiler suppose to know that `T` has a method called `fromJson()`. Of course this method can never work like that. Imagine you call this method like `reviveObject<SomeOtherClass>(value)`, then T doesn't have this method

Comment: @IvoBeckers Granted! But then the compiler could complain about the instantiation of the method with a non fitting type. Another method revives List<T> JSON. On T, I can perfectly call T.toString().

Comment: It's a bit different to your situation I think but this is an interesting discussion about something similar: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/356

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not possible, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56138419/12156637) know more details

TL;DR

> Dart static method invocations are resolved at compile-time, so it's not possible to call them on type variables which only have a value at run-time.

I got over this by passing the from json function of the Type that i want

i.e

```
T? reviveObject<T>( dynamic value, T Function(Object? json) fromJsonT ) {
```

Comment: But if method invocations are resolved at compile time, at exactly that time, the actual type is known. In reviveObject<EItem>(value ) the exact type EItem is known at compile time. Doesn't it?

Comment: EItem is known at compile time, but reviveObject doesn't know that the generic type T is of type EItem at compile-time, it only knows this when the function gets called, i.e in runtime

Comment: You proposal worked just fine. Thx! But I still believe that the type checker should do better. Ivo Beckers posted this interesting link: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/356