# How to make dart function generic?

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

I have a basic FirebaseManager, currently it parses and returns only a list of User(). How can I make it parse and return any class?

It needs to be something like this:

```
  final result = await manager.read<User>();
  final result = await manager.read<Address>();
  final result = await manager.read<Contacts>();
```

Usage of current manager.

```
Future _firebaseFirestoreTest() async {
  final manager = FirebaseManager(CollectionName.newAction);
  final result = await manager.read();
  print(result);
}
```

```
class FirebaseManager implements DataSourceRepository {
  final CollectionReference _collection;

  FirebaseManager(String collectionName)
      : _collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionName);

  @override
  Future<List<User>> read() async {
    final snapshot = await _collection.get();
    final data = <User>[];

    for (final document in snapshot.docs) {
      final json = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final object = User.fromJson(json);
      data.add(object);
    }

    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use [dynamic](https://dart.dev/language/type-system).

Comment: @tomerpacific, it's not a problem to return a dynamic class. We can also use 'T,' but when it actually comes to parsing, there is an issue.

Comment: [There are many questions similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdart%5D+t.fromjson). `static` methods and constructors in Dart are not part of a type's interface, so there is no way for a generic function to call a constructor or `static` method given only a type.  Instead have callers pass `fromJson` as a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, it's not possible to do this in Dart (or at least in Flutter) in a generic way. Static members of a class are not part of the type parameter available to generic functions, so there's no way of calling a factory constructor or static method on a generic type. The most straightforward way of achieving this functionality is to pass a parsing callback to the function:

```dart
Future<List<T>> read<T>(T Function(Map<String, dynamic>) parser) async {
  final snapshot = await _collection.get();
  final data = <User>[];

  for (final document in snapshot.docs) {
    final json = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final object = parser(json);
    data.add(object);
  }

  return data;
}
```

```dart
final result = await manager.read<User>(User.fromJson);
final result = await manager.read<Address>(Address.fromJson);
final result = await manager.read<Contacts>(Contacts.fromJson);
```

There is a slightly more convenient way, although it requires some setup and can't be used dynamically. Instead of passing the parsing methods to the `read` function, keep a lookup table of types with known parsing functions. You can then use them in the `read` function directly using the generic type as the key:

```dart
typedef T _Parser<T>(Map<String, dynamic> map);
final Map<Type, _Parser> _parsers = {
  User: User.fromJson,
  Address: Address.fromJson,
  Contacts: Contacts.fromJson,
};

class FirebaseManager implements DataSourceRepository {
  // ...
  
  @override
  Future<List<T>> read<T>() async {
    final parser = _parsers[T];
    if (parser == null) {
      throw ArgumentError('Unsupported parsable type $T');
    }
    
    final snapshot = await _collection.get();
    final data = <T>[];

    for (final document in snapshot.docs) {
      final json = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final object = parser(json) as T;
      data.add(object);
    }

    return data;
  }
}
```

```dart
final result = await manager.read<User>();
final result = await manager.read<Address>();
final result = await manager.read<Contacts>();
```

Comment: This sounds like the closest thing to what you want to achieve. I'll leave my answer up for completeness' sake, but this is an actual solution to your problem

Answer (score -1):

##### This solution doesn't work completely. Check out the other answer by @Abion47 above ^

You can partially achieve this with generics. Check out the documentation here:
https://dart.dev/language/generics

For your example, you can include a type `T` when calling the `read` function, so it'll know to return this type (if no type is passed, it will just use and return `dynamic`, which would fail in the `fromJson` I guess).

```dart
Future<List<T>> read<T>() async {
  ...
  final data = <T>[];
  ...
    final object = T.fromJson(json);
  ...
  return data;
}
```

Which you would indeed call like this:

```dart
final result = await manager.read<User>(); // type of result becomes List<User>
```

### Update

My first thought given your update: since `isJson` isn't defined for a generic type `T`, perhaps you can define a shared supertype for all of your serializable classes? The problem is that `fromJson` is a static method, and these are not inherited by subclasses...

So I'm not sure how I'd get this to work. Let's hope someone more knowledgeable on the topic comes around and can help us to figure this out.

### Update #2

Looking at this other SO post, it's not possible to call a static method on a generic type in Dart: [Calling a static method from a generic constraint Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135525/calling-a-static-method-from-a-generic-constraint-dart)

Comment: Unfortunately, T.fromJson() doesn't work. The method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was afraid of. I couldn't run the full code since I don't have all the Firebase things, so I wasn't able to check

Comment: I just updated my answer, it boils down to: It's not possible using generics, perhaps you can define a non-static method to go from json and make all classes inherit that?

Comment: You can do it for a list of specific types, using a switch to dispatch to the proper constructor.  I should have a video out on this shortly.